# automatic update record at the end of day, laravel

Tags: html, laravel, controller, sql-update, calculated-columns

i am developing simple loan management system and i want my accumulated loan amount to be updated at the end of every day.

In my DB, for a specific user, lets guess column named loanamount has a value of 10000, interestrate is 3% monthly.
First column is loanamount, second column is interestrate.
Third column is accumulatedloan and it should be automatically updated everyday as 10000 * 3/30, 10000 * 3 * 2/30, 10000 * 3*3/30 etc. How can i set this automatic third column in controller?

Comment: Hello @Bayakaa Gungaajav. You can do it using schedule cron job in laravel

Answer (score 0):

In this case a scheduled tasks probably is the best solution here. Please refer to the Laravel Docs on the topic for further information: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

if you want to update data every day, you should use cron, however you could probably consider make a dynamic property in laravel. Just add loan start day (created_at) and then you can easily calculate how many days the loan is active.

then make something like

```
public function activeLoanAmountAttribute()
{
   your code here
}
```

than you can access your loan amount with:

```
$this->activeLoanAmount;
```

or just make an function